# Drawing a line with two different colors using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to draw a line using D3 with two different colors. I achieving something similar using rectangle over a portion of the line and then adding some opacity to it.

But the problem with this solution is that the background also gets a bit opaque.

Is there a way to achieve the same result but only with the line?

**Edit:** 
The change of color can be anywhere in the path, it depends on the data. There's a circle representing the point of interest in the path, before that circle it should be of one color, after it should be of another color.

Here's a sample of the code I've been using so far.

```js
var width = 200;
var height = 25;
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 4, 0]);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %d, %Y").parse;
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .interpolate("linear") // use basis for rounded
             .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
             .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

function sparkline(elemId, data, lo, hi, targetPoint) {

 targetPoint = data1.length - targetPoint;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.close = +d.Close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  var svg = d3.select(elemId)
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', width)
              .attr('height', height)
              .append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 2)');
   


    svg.append('path')
     .datum(data)
     .attr('class', 'sparkline')
     .attr('d', line);
     

  svg.append('circle')
     .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
     .attr('cx', x(data[data.length - targetPoint].date))
     .attr('cy', y(data[data.length - targetPoint].close))
     .attr('r', 2.5);  

    
    svg.append('rect')   
    .attr('class', 'sparkrange')
    .attr("x", x(data[0].date))
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", x(data[data.length - targetPoint].date) - x(data[0].date) - 2)
    .attr("height", 30);

}

var data1 = [
    {"Date": "Feb 1, 2014", "Close": "26"},
    {"Date": "Feb 2, 2014", "Close": "27"},
    {"Date": "Feb 3, 2014", "Close": "29"},
    {"Date": "Feb 4, 2014", "Close": "23"},
    {"Date": "Feb 5, 2014", "Close": "22"},
    {"Date": "Feb 5, 2014", "Close": "22"},
    {"Date": "Feb 8, 2014", "Close": "24"},
    {"Date": "Feb 9, 2014", "Close": "29"},
    {"Date": "Feb 10, 2014", "Close": "26"},
    {"Date": "Feb 11, 2014", "Close": "25"}
];

var targetPoint = 3;
sparkline('#spark1', data1, 24.3, 25.6, targetPoint);
```

```css
body{
  
  background:#fff;
}

#spark1{

}
svg{

}
.sparkline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4B95FF;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.sparkcircle {
  fill: #4B95FF;
  stroke: none;
}
.sparkrange{
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.sparkline.bold{
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>D3 sparkline hack to give the illusion of different weights</p>

<div style="display:flex">
<div id="spark1"></div>
<div id="sparkOpaque"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed position for changing the color, or can it be anywhere in the path?

Comment: anywhere in the path. it depends on the data

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a linear gradient:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green");
```

Here, `point` is your original `targetPoint`. I also increased the height and width of the line, to make the color change more noticeable.

This is the demo:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 40;
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 4, 0]);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %d, %Y").parse;
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear") // use basis for rounded
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

function sparkline(elemId, data, lo, hi, targetPoint) {

  var point = targetPoint;

  targetPoint = data1.length - targetPoint;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.close = +d.Close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.close;
  }));

  var svg = d3.select(elemId)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 2)');

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset",  (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green");

  svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'sparkline')
    .attr('d', line)
    .style("stroke", "url(#gradient)");

  svg.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
    .attr('cx', x(data[data.length - targetPoint].date))
    .attr('cy', y(data[data.length - targetPoint].close))
    .attr('r', 2.5);

}

var data1 = [{
  "Date": "Feb 1, 2014",
  "Close": "26"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 2, 2014",
  "Close": "27"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 3, 2014",
  "Close": "29"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 4, 2014",
  "Close": "23"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "22"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "22"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 8, 2014",
  "Close": "24"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 9, 2014",
  "Close": "29"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 10, 2014",
  "Close": "26"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 11, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}];

var targetPoint = 3;
sparkline('#spark1', data1, 24.3, 25.6, targetPoint);
```

```css
.sparkline {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="spark1"></div>
```

Comment: That worked, but there's an issue and I'd like to see if you can help me, if all values are the same no line is shown. Say all Close values are 25. There's no line

Comment: Well, that's another issue, so please post another question.

Comment: I surely can, but I didn't have this issue before using the solution you proposed above.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Sorry, I thought it was unrelated. Just set the `gradientUnits` to `userSpaceOnUse`: https://jsfiddle.net/wb4veyus/